# rest api SOQL Query max records

Tags: soql, rest-api

The documentation states that if it cannot return all records in the query then you can use the next records URL to get more records. Does this still have the same limitation of no more than 50,000 records overall. If I run SELECT+Id+FROM+Account and there are 100,000 accounts will it just hard stop me at 50,000 or will it let me continue or is there some other limit?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The batchSize limit (200-2000) will be applied to a REST API query. Note that this is a "suggestion" to the server; it may alter the batch size if there are many fields or large fields that are queried. See the [Query Options Header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_queryoptions.htm) for more information. In general, you can query up to 50,000,000 records in a REST API query, but they will be paged at most every 2,000 records.

Comment: What you mean in general you can query 50mil. Is there a limit to query more than that?

Answer (score 2):

> Does this still have the same limitation of no more than 50,000 records overall.

No. The 50,000 SOQL row limit applies to Apex transactions. It does *not* apply to queries executed via the REST API.